# Does pine script allow buy and sell orders at the same time?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have been trying to get pinescript to open buy and sell orders without closing orders in the opposite direction.   Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you need this? Couldn't you adjust your buy or sell sizing to functionally be doing the same thing?

Comment: My strategy takes buys and sells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Hedging is currently not supported.

If you really need this, you can create an indicator and simulate all the strategy behavior there.

Comment: thank you, when you say create an indicator and simulate all the strategy behaviour there, how can I simulate the strategy when the script is in indicator mode?

Comment: WIth bunch of variables and manual calculations.